# How to check if a tweet was sent with tweetinvi

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

How do you check if a tweet was successfully published?

```
public static void TestTweet()
        {
            Auth.SetUserCredentials(
               "xxx",
               "xxx",
               "xxx",
               "xxx");

            var user = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
            
            //Successful since length is short
            Tweet.PublishTweet("Test Again");

            //Unsuccessful since length is too long but no error is thrown in c# app
            Tweet.PublishTweet("id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod");
        }
```

The first published tweet is sent successfully because it is within the 140-character limit but the second tweet is unsuccessful since it is too long.

If I only call the method above, the program completes successfully as if the second tweet was tweeted successfully but when I look at my twitter account, the tweet doesn't show up. Is there a way to check if my published tweet actually published correctly?

Comment: Does `Tweet.PublishTweet` return a value?

Comment: The Tweet limit is 280 characters for the majority of languages, FWIW. If PublishTweet() returns an ID, you could then query for it.

Comment: I guess this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502701/finding-the-tweetid-of-a-tweet-in-tweetinvi